# Does the nutrition facts label include "packaging"?

Tags: nutrient-composition

Does the nutrition facts label include "packaging"?

For example, for "sardines packed in oil", does the label refer to drained sardines, or everything in the container?

---

*Edit:* I sometimes forget that other countries exist. I'm mostly interested in U.S. nutritional facts labels. Nothing on the packaging says how it should be interpreted (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, the nutition information (for tinned fish) is given after draining: [Tesco sardines](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/258574380).  This is specified on the packaging.

How well drained is another matter, but there's enough information on the packaging - the drained weight is given as 84g while the contents is 120g, so to achieve the stated nutrition values, you'd need to drain off 36g of oil.

You use the term "nutrition facts", which is used in a few countries (not mine); it's up to the authority that writes the labelling regulations, but whether drained or not should be clearly stated if those regulations are fit for purpose.  If yours aren't labelled sufficiently, look for a simliar product that is, such as the one I've linked.